# JAXB/Moxy marshalling of fields defined as interfaces to JSON

Tags: java, json, jaxb, moxy

I'm working on a program which will marshal a POJO to JSON format. I do this using Moxy and this all works fine - except for cases where a field is referenced through one of its implemented interfaces.

For example:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Customer {
    public String name;
    public Address address;
    public ICustomerRelation relation;
}
```

Here we have a Customer class with a simple "name" field, a class "Address" and a "relation" which is referenced by an interface.

The name field is marshalled without problems to something like name: "John Smith".

The Address field is also marshalled without problems, to something like `"address: { street: "Streetname" }"`. Note: The Address field is of course also annotated with `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)`.

But the "relation" field is marshalled as if it had no fields or properties. For example: "relation: { }".

I tried annotating the `ICustomerRelation` interface with `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)` hoping that this annotation would be inherited to the concrete implementation classes, but Java does not support that.

I tried annotating the concrete implementations of `ICustomerRelation` with `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)`, but this also had no effect. I suspect Moxy is looking at the declared type rather than the concrete implementation.

I tried annotating the relation field with `@XmlAnyElement` which then lead to an error stating something to the effect of "Class (concrete class) has no root element". Annotating the concrete class with `@XmlName(name="x")` did not appear solve that.

Perhaps there are no good solutions to this. I understand that marshalling an interface makes it very hard to unmarshall the resulting JSON, because which concrete implementation should be created to receive the values?

I'm looking for anyone who has run into a similar problem and how you ended up solving it.